# How to make two different modules in Android Studio use different versions of the same library via Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have two modules in my Android app: `app` and `library`. `app` depends on `library`

In `library` I want to use `AndroidAnnotations 4.0.0`

In `app` I want to currently use `AndroidAnnotations 3.2.2` because upgrading it to 4.0.0 would require an enormous amount of changes, as they've changed it quite a lot, and I don't have time to do this right now.

However, ever since I upgraded `library` to use `AndroidAnnotations 4.0.0`, the usage of `AndroidAnnotations` in `app` behaves as it is version 4, not version 3, which makes me think that Gradle was really smart and ignored version 3 for `app` and is using version 4 for both modules.

How can I enforce the usage of two different versions of a dependency in gradle?

Comment: You can't have two different versions since there'll be namespace clashes. The only way it's possible is by repackaging one of the versions yourself and changing the package name of the classes so they don't clash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enforce the use of a dependency version over another using the [force](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force%28java.lang.Object[]%29) command

`build.gradle`(app):

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0') {
        force = true
    }
    ...
}
```

`build.gradle`(library):

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    ...
}
```

Here is excerpt from the docs if the link goes invalid:

> Allows forcing certain versions of dependencies, including transitive
>   dependencies. Appends new forced modules to be considered when
>   resolving dependencies.
>
> It accepts following notations:
>
> ```
> String in a format of: 'group:name:version', for example: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:1.0'
> instance of ModuleVersionSelector
> any collection or array of above will be automatically flattened
> ```